# Mock Function with Jest and Enzyme Failing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to get a simple test with mock function working with a basic React app, but it's failing and I can't pinpoint where I've gone wrong. Can anyone set me straight?

**Main App.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import List from './List';

    class App extends Component {

      state = {
        count: 0,
        newItem: '',
        items: ['apple', 'milk'] 
      }

      addItem = () => {
        if (this.state.newItem) {
       this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1, items: [...this.state.items, this.state.newItem], newItem: '' })
       } 
      }

      render() {

      return(
      <div className="App">

         <header className="App-header">
          <h1>30 days of React</h1>
          <h2>Day Thirty / Testing React Components</h2>
          <p>Total Items: {this.state.count}</p>
         </header>

         <div className="container">
          <input type='text' value={this.state.newItem} onChange={e => this.setState({ newItem: e.target.value})}></input>
          <button className='main-btn' onClick = {this.addItem}>Add To List</button>
         </div>

        <div>
          <List items={this.state.items}/>
        </div>

        </div>

        ) 
       }
     }

    export default App;
```

**Test**

```
//define empty mock function to simulate the click 
const mockClick = jest.fn();

describe('App component mock test', () => {
    it('button click should fire function', () => {
        const component = shallow(<App onClick={mockClick} />);

        const input = component.find('input');
        input.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'test'} });

        const button = component.find('button.main-btn');
        button.simulate('click');
        expect(mockClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

There is also one functional component that renders the list, but as this is a shallow test it shouldn't come into play.

Comment: Your component doesn't use *any* of its props, it's not clear why you'd expect `mockClick` to get invoked. The actual behaviour is to add a new item in the items shown in `List`, you should test for that (either checking the props to `List`, diving or using a deeper render).

Comment: Because the button is clicked no? This is simply a project for me to understand how to test, I realize this isn't a real-world case etc...
Will move on to testing deeper renders to test exactly this after I nail this more basic one :)

Comment: But why would you expect that to invoke `this.props.onClick` for the `App`component, given that isn't ever accessed?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by 'accessed' sorry? And thanks so far for your help :)

Comment: I don't know how else to put it. Referenced? Where within App do you use any of its props?

Comment: OK figured it out. D'oh. Basically I was just confused about how mocks work and their use case. I get it now. Created a child component with onCick as a prop to simply test that the function is firing, Now it is workign and my nderstanding is better.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out. D'oh. Basically I was just confused about how mocks work and their use case. I get it now. Created a child component with onCick as a prop to simply test that the function is firing, Now it is working.

**test**

```
const mockClick = jest.fn();

describe('ListItem component mock tests', () => {
    it('button click should fire function', () => {
        const component = shallow(<ListItem onClick={mockClick} />);

        const button = component.find('button.smallbtn');
        button.simulate('click');
        expect(mockClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

**child component i'm testing**

```
import React from 'react';
const ListItem = ( props ) => {

return (

  <div>
    <p>{props.item}</p>
    <button className="smallbtn" onClick={() => props.onClick(props.id)}>delete</button>  
  </div>

  );
};

export default ListItem;
```